# Python. Remove words from .txt file

Tags: python

I'm using this code to get all users from Telegram group

```
while True:
    participants = client(GetParticipantsRequest(
        channel, ChannelParticipantsSearch(''), offset, limit, hash=0
    ))
    if not participants.users:
        break
    all_participants.extend(participants.users)
    offset += len(participants.users)
    print(offset)
    print(all_participants)
```

The output is is in format - `[<telethon.tl.types.User object at 0x03AFB3D0>]`

Then:

```
thefile = open('file.txt', 'w')

#for participant in all_participants:
    #thefile.write("%s\n" % participant)

    #print(all_participants)
```

And my file now has a lot of rows with a lot of info(I removed a lot not to make it look messy)

```
User(is_self=False, contact=False,, first_name='NAME', last_name=NAME, username='HIS_USERNAME')
```

How can I remove everthing and just have HIS_USERNAME in file?
So instead of rows with full info, I would like to have usernames only.

I know that the best way would be using Telegram API but I haven't found the way to get usernames only.

Comment: Presumably there is a way to get just the username.  Perhaps `participant.username`?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes..You're right. Thank you